# Exception from sub meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor. After creating the default meteor project and running it, I am getting this error:

> Exception from sub meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions id 7AsCuXcz8A9yRRNm5
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property '_failIfArgumentsAreNotAllChecked' of undefined

My `meteor` version is `1.4.3.2`

Comment: I uninstalled meteor and then reinstalled it and everything ran fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall meteor and reinstall. Everything will be ok.